# Rendering a web page by browsers

Tags: sockets, browser, tcp

I typed "Rendering a web page by browsers" in google and I obtained the following [link](http://friendlybit.com/css/rendering-a-web-page-step-by-step/).
According to this description HTTP requests for every resource connected with one page are made via separated TCP socket. I always thought that only one TCP socket is established and all resources (images, CSS and JS files) are sent through this socket. If am not clear enough: You type www.example.com in address bar of the browser. Let's say the web page under this address has N pictures and M CSS and JS files. How many TCP socket are opened by browser? 1+N+M?

Comment: It depends on a bunch of factors. There is no one answer.

Comment: Browser-cached resources, the number of different domains that these static resources (images, JS, CSS) are on, HTTP connection headers, etc.

Comment: OK, so let's say there is no cache, resources come from one server. What's then?

Comment: It still depends on other factors, like the HTTP connection reuse settings, as controlled by HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes HTTP is a stateless protocol. Every resource a page needs is downloaded sepperately by your browser. That is html, flash / silverlight etc, images, css, js and so on. To optimize load times it's recommended to merge all css and all js into one file to reduce the ammount if requests needed to load a page.

Comment: I agree with you that HTTP is stateless. But since TCP is not I though one socket is enough to obtain all resources.